# How to set nginx redirection to mvc php app?

Tags: php, nginx, url-routing

I have problem with redirection from nginx to php mvc app, because all requests sending from nginx are looking for directory. I would like to send url as params to let the routes in app menage them. Both of them are on different servers.

.htaccess in app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|svg|json|pdf|php)$ [NC]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

in nginx i tried:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

May i ask for advice how to configure redirection from nginx to mvc app. Is there any tag in header of request which tells the server that request looking for directory?

Example:
https://site.domain/Users

In this example Users is a directory, i would like to use it as "string param"

Example of request i received in app:

```
IP - - [26/Mar/2020:15:13:20 +0000] "GET /Application/Admin?id=1322323 HTTP/1.0" 403 466 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
```

In this example Application is root directorywhich work correct but after "/" is a Folder.. no param string..

Comment: Have you considered using a framework like Laravel? This would be quite easy there and it takes very little effort to get started.

Comment: Actually no but app is finished and change now gonna be labor-intensive. OK, if Laravel solve this issue how he do that? it is an issue of app configuration or nginx?

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. I didnt consider that such a problem might be encountered at the end of a project. In that case, using a framework now might not be a valid option. Ill let others more familiar with nginx answer your original question.

Comment: This is probably something you should have considered _before_ designing the whole application.

Comment: I will explain it other way. You can design app and sell it. If someone buy your app and set on server which is hidden behid server with nginx, for me not logical is we blame app.   Because as we know http request is unified form

Comment: If i send request to server where app is all work correctly, but if i do that through nginx, there is a problem

Comment: You have an Apache configuration file in your question. Is this application using both Nginx and Apache?

Answer (score 1):

For nginx is enough the following (You don't need any query params binding - they will work ok)

```
location ~ ^/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

For apache I would do

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301]
```

Let us know the outcome